# Is there a better way to get to Workbench context in an E4 application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm working with an E4 application and am currently in a Part. I want to push a flag at the Workbench level context and the only way that I could get to it is

```
context.getParent().getParent().getParent().set("FLAG", false);
```

Is there a better way to get to the Workbench level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workbench context is accessible from the application object:

```
@Inject
MApplication application;

...

IEclipseContext appContext = application.getContext();
```

Using `getParent()` calls is very error prone as any change to the application model may break the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Inject
IEclipseContext eclipseContext;
```

Of course You must be in E4ApplicationModel. If not, You can inject this (in Processor/LifeCycleManager/other in E4ApplicationModel...):

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(myClass,eclipseContext);
```